# EditText in scroll view in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I try to create a from application, in the app I have a lengthy form which I want to be in a scroll view, But when I add EditText to the scrollView ..the eclipse shows some error in its designer view.

```
error!
IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

Any one have an idea to crack it out?

---

I have included this code after getting a solution for the above trouble..!

Now the EditText is not showing any typed text, it just gives some suggestions...!

I have the following XML :

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/widget64"
android:layout_width="320px"
android:layout_height="358px"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:saveEnabled="true">
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget58"
android:layout_width="320px"
android:layout_height="65px"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget60"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/user"
android:text="User"
android:textColor="#000000">
</TextView>
</TableRow>
<TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget60"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/users_first_name" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:hint="First Name"
android:focusable="true"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:enabled="true"
android:ems="15">
</EditText>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

Found the trouble.....
My emulator key was set to Chinese instead of English...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First add any layout to that scrollview and then add edittext to that layout.Then automatically u got the scrolling for that edittext .For Ex:add Linearlayout to that scrollview and then add editText to taht linearlayout.

Comment: clik on the left side top of the left side

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `ScrollVew` can have only one child. 
For this do something like this

```
<ScrollView
   fillViewPortView = "true">

    <RelativeLayout>
          // Design the entire layout in here
          // Put your elements one below the other. It will automatically scroll
          // dont forget to setFillViewPort view to true in ScrollView
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This will solve the problem for sure
Hope his help : )

Comment: if it helps Accept the answer by selecting the check on the left side.
It will help others too

Comment: Now the typed text are not appearing on the EditText..!

Comment: Are you viewing the edittext but not able to see the text in it after pressing the key from soft keyboard..If this is so.then check the color of text you might have changed. Put a simple default edittext in the layout without any modification for test. and let me know the result

Comment: yep...! there are suggestions coming ..but they are in some Chinese or Japanese....

Comment: post the image of screen shot in here. is it the default edit text you are using in a layout. because it is not supposed to behave like this.. Make a separate project with its main layout with one outer scrollview and one inner view main and put edittext in it. test this.

Comment: Do some permutation and combination of your code and project, you will learn the platform better

Comment: OK so the whole discussion didn't come out to be helpful.

Comment: Do you see any trouble with the above XML...?

Comment: I cannot post images since I am a new user and cannot vote up...sorry please help me in the above issue...!

Comment: When you have more then one answer you can select only one out of it that helps you the most.

Comment: Its My personal preference Not to use TableLayout it create a lot of Headache. I use Relative Layout and it resolve everything for me. Try and use Relative layout

Comment: Ok ...Have any idea on the present issue?

Comment: rahul i hope you selected the right answer that helps you out in real..
In stackoverflow when you will get more then one answer. You are suppose to check only one answer that helps you the most.